# Port of Ubercart "Dependant Atributes" or "Chained Attributes" modules

Tags: 7, ubercart

Do you know of a Drupal 7 version of either of these modules?

1. [Ubercart dependant atributes](http://drupal.org/project/uc_dependent_attributes)
2. [Chained Attributes and Options](http://www.ubercart.org/project/uc_cano)

I've spent a couple of days trying to find an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be slightly late judging by your ask date but I figured I would post it anyway.

This module performs similar to the above.

https://drupal.org/node/1192892

Comment: Where can you download uc_dropdown_attributes for Drupal 7?